# Chartist.js - increase spacing between scale points of Y Axis

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg

I am working on a personal project creating graphs to show data about my music listening habits from Last FM's API.

I am grabbing the JSON data via an AJAX request and then using the returned JSON objects to populate a graph created using the Chartist.js JS library.

I'm having what I consider a quite straightforward issue in that I can't work out how to increase the overall size of the chart? To be more specific I'd like to increase the spacing between each scale point on the Y axis so that you can see more accurately what each figure is.

I have created the following JS Fiddle to show my problem:

http://jsfiddle.net/jt96usn9/

According to the documentation, I believe I need to change an option attribute known as scaleMinSpace but upon changing this figure no changes seem to occur.

Any help would be great?!

```js
var lastfm = {};

lastfm.tracker = (function(){

 //Set up an object for DOM elements and data source
 var config = {
  getRecentTracksURL: "http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=user.getrecenttracks&user=jimmersjukebox&api_key=6db1989bd348bf91797bad802c6645d8&format=json",
  getMostPopularArtistsURL: "http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=user.gettopartists&user=jimmersjukebox&api_key=6db1989bd348bf91797bad802c6645d8&format=json",
  user: "jimmersjukebox",
  recentTracksElement: $(".recent-tracks"),
  currentlyPlayingActiveClass: $(".current")
 };


 var setupLastFM = function(){
  createPopularArtistsChart();
 };



 var createPopularArtistsChart = function(){


  $.getJSON(config.getMostPopularArtistsURL,function(data){
   var artistData = data.topartists.artist,
   artists = $.map(artistData, function(artist) {
    return [[artist.name]];
   }),

   playcounts = $.map(artistData, function(playcount) {
    return [[playcount.playcount]];
   });


   // These are the default options of the line chart
   var options = {
     // Options for X-Axis
     axisX: {
       // The offset of the labels to the chart area
       offset: 10,
       // If labels should be shown or not
       showLabel: true,
       // If the axis grid should be drawn or not
       showGrid: true,
       // Interpolation function that allows you to intercept the value from the axis label
       labelInterpolationFnc: function(value){return value;}
     },
     // Options for Y-Axis
     axisY: {
       scaleMinSpace: 100
     },
     // Specify a fixed width for the chart as a string (i.e. '100px' or '50%')
     width: undefined,
     // Specify a fixed height for the chart as a string (i.e. '100px' or '50%')
     height: undefined,
     // If the line should be drawn or not
     showLine: true,
     // If dots should be drawn or not
     showPoint: true,
     // Specify if the lines should be smoothed (Catmull-Rom-Splines will be used)
     lineSmooth: true,
     // Overriding the natural low of the chart allows you to zoom in or limit the charts lowest displayed value
     low: undefined,
     // Overriding the natural high of the chart allows you to zoom in or limit the charts highest displayed value
     high: undefined,
     // Padding of the chart drawing area to the container element and labels
     chartPadding: 15,
     // Specify the distance in pixel of bars in a group
     seriesBarDistance: 15,
     // Override the class names that get used to generate the SVG structure of the chart

   };

   data = {
     // A labels array that can contain any sort of values
     labels: artists.slice(0,10),
     // Our series array that contains series objects or in this case series data arrays
     series: [
      playcounts.slice(0,10)
     ]
   };

   // Create a new line chart object where as first parameter we pass in a selector
   // that is resolving to our chart container element. The Second parameter
   // is the actual data object.
   Chartist.Bar('.ct-chart', data, options);

  });



 };

 return{
  config: config,
  init: function(){
   setupLastFM();
  }
 };
})();
$(window).load(lastfm.tracker.init);
```

```css
/* Chartist.js 0.2.4
 * Copyright © 2014 Gion Kunz
 * Free to use under the WTFPL license.
 * http://www.wtfpl.net/
 */

.ct-chart .ct-label{fill:rgba(0,0,0,.4);font-size:.75rem}.ct-chart .ct-grid{stroke:rgba(0,0,0,.2);stroke-width:1px;stroke-dasharray:2px}.ct-chart .ct-point{stroke-width:10px;stroke-linecap:round}.ct-chart .ct-line{fill:none;stroke-width:4px}.ct-chart .ct-area{stroke:none;fill-opacity:.1}.ct-chart .ct-bar{fill:none;stroke-width:10px}.ct-chart .ct-slice.ct-donut{fill:none;stroke-width:60px}.ct-chart .ct-series.ct-series-a .ct-bar,.ct-chart .ct-series.ct-series-a .ct-line,.ct-chart .ct-series.ct-series-a .ct-point,.ct-chart .ct-series.ct-series-a .ct-slice.ct-donut{stroke:#d70206}.ct-chart .ct-series.ct-series-a .ct-area,.ct-chart .ct-series.ct-series-a .ct-slice:not(.ct-donut){fill:#d70206}.ct-chart .ct-series.ct-series-b .ct-bar,.ct-chart .ct-series.ct-series-b .ct-line,.ct-chart .ct-series.ct-series-b .ct-point,.ct-chart .ct-series.ct-series-b .ct-slice.ct-donut{stroke:#F05B4F}.ct-chart .ct-series.ct-series-b .ct-area,.ct-chart .ct-series.ct-series-b .ct-slice:not(.ct-donut){fill:#F05B4F}.ct-chart .ct-series.ct-series-c .ct-bar,.ct-chart .ct-series.ct-series-c .ct-line,.ct-chart .ct-series.ct-series-c .ct-point,.ct-chart .ct-series.ct-series-c .ct-slice.ct-donut{stroke:#F4C63D}.ct-chart .ct-series.ct-series-c .ct-area,.ct-chart .ct-series.ct-series-c .ct-slice:not(.ct-donut){fill:#F4C63D}.ct-chart .ct-series.ct-series-d .ct-bar,.ct-chart .ct-series.ct-series-d .ct-line,.ct-chart .ct-series.ct-series-d .ct-point,.ct-chart .ct-series.ct-series-d .ct-slice.ct-donut{stroke:#453D3F}.ct-chart .ct-series.ct-series-d .ct-area,.ct-chart .ct-series.ct-series-d .ct-slice:not(.ct-donut){fill:#453D3F}.ct-chart.ct-square{display:block;position:relative;width:100%}.ct-chart.ct-square:before{display:block;float:left;content:"";width:0;height:0;padding-bottom:100%}.ct-chart.ct-square:after{content:"";display:table;clear:both}.ct-chart.ct-square>svg{display:block;position:absolute;top:0;left:0}.ct-chart.ct-minor-second{display:block;position:relative;width:100%}.ct-chart.ct-minor-second:before{display:block;float:left;content:"";width:0;height:0;padding-bottom:93.75%}.ct-chart.ct-minor-second:after{content:"";display:table;clear:both}.ct-chart.ct-minor-second>svg{display:block;position:absolute;top:0;left:0}.ct-chart.ct-major-second{display:block;position:relative;width:100%}.ct-chart.ct-major-second:before{display:block;float:left;content:"";width:0;height:0;padding-bottom:88.8888888889%}.ct-chart.ct-major-second:after{content:"";display:table;clear:both}.ct-chart.ct-major-second>svg{display:block;position:absolute;top:0;left:0}.ct-chart.ct-minor-third{display:block;position:relative;width:100%}.ct-chart.ct-minor-third:before{display:block;float:left;content:"";width:0;height:0;padding-bottom:83.3333333333%}.ct-chart.ct-minor-third:after{content:"";display:table;clear:both}.ct-chart.ct-minor-third>svg{display:block;position:absolute;top:0;left:0}.ct-chart.ct-major-third{display:block;position:relative;width:100%}.ct-chart.ct-major-third:before{display:block;float:left;content:"";width:0;height:0;padding-bottom:80%}.ct-chart.ct-major-third:after{content:"";display:table;clear:both}.ct-chart.ct-major-third>svg{display:block;position:absolute;top:0;left:0}.ct-chart.ct-perfect-fourth{display:block;position:relative;width:100%}.ct-chart.ct-perfect-fourth:before{display:block;float:left;content:"";width:0;height:0;padding-bottom:75%}.ct-chart.ct-perfect-fourth:after{content:"";display:table;clear:both}.ct-chart.ct-perfect-fourth>svg{display:block;position:absolute;top:0;left:0}.ct-chart.ct-perfect-fifth{display:block;position:relative;width:100%}.ct-chart.ct-perfect-fifth:before{display:block;float:left;content:"";width:0;height:0;padding-bottom:66.6666666667%}.ct-chart.ct-perfect-fifth:after{content:"";display:table;clear:both}.ct-chart.ct-perfect-fifth>svg{display:block;position:absolute;top:0;left:0}.ct-chart.ct-minor-sixth{display:block;position:relative;width:100%}.ct-chart.ct-minor-sixth:before{display:block;float:left;content:"";width:0;height:0;padding-bottom:62.5%}.ct-chart.ct-minor-sixth:after{content:"";display:table;clear:both}.ct-chart.ct-minor-sixth>svg{display:block;position:absolute;top:0;left:0}.ct-chart.ct-golden-section{display:block;position:relative;width:100%}.ct-chart.ct-golden-section:before{display:block;float:left;content:"";width:0;height:0;padding-bottom:61.804697157%}.ct-chart.ct-golden-section:after{content:"";display:table;clear:both}.ct-chart.ct-golden-section>svg{display:block;position:absolute;top:0;left:0}.ct-chart.ct-major-sixth{display:block;position:relative;width:100%}.ct-chart.ct-major-sixth:before{display:block;float:left;content:"";width:0;height:0;padding-bottom:60%}.ct-chart.ct-major-sixth:after{content:"";display:table;clear:both}.ct-chart.ct-major-sixth>svg{display:block;position:absolute;top:0;left:0}.ct-chart.ct-minor-seventh{display:block;position:relative;width:100%}.ct-chart.ct-minor-seventh:before{display:block;float:left;content:"";width:0;height:0;padding-bottom:56.25%}.ct-chart.ct-minor-seventh:after{content:"";display:table;clear:both}.ct-chart.ct-minor-seventh>svg{display:block;position:absolute;top:0;left:0}.ct-chart.ct-major-seventh{display:block;position:relative;width:100%}.ct-chart.ct-major-seventh:before{display:block;float:left;content:"";width:0;height:0;padding-bottom:53.3333333333%}.ct-chart.ct-major-seventh:after{content:"";display:table;clear:both}.ct-chart.ct-major-seventh>svg{display:block;position:absolute;top:0;left:0}.ct-chart.ct-octave{display:block;position:relative;width:100%}.ct-chart.ct-octave:before{display:block;float:left;content:"";width:0;height:0;padding-bottom:50%}.ct-chart.ct-octave:after{content:"";display:table;clear:both}.ct-chart.ct-octave>svg{display:block;position:absolute;top:0;left:0}.ct-chart.ct-major-tenth{display:block;position:relative;width:100%}.ct-chart.ct-major-tenth:before{display:block;float:left;content:"";width:0;height:0;padding-bottom:40%}.ct-chart.ct-major-tenth:after{content:"";display:table;clear:both}.ct-chart.ct-major-tenth>svg{display:block;position:absolute;top:0;left:0}.ct-chart.ct-major-eleventh{display:block;position:relative;width:100%}.ct-chart.ct-major-eleventh:before{display:block;float:left;content:"";width:0;height:0;padding-bottom:37.5%}.ct-chart.ct-major-eleventh:after{content:"";display:table;clear:both}.ct-chart.ct-major-eleventh>svg{display:block;position:absolute;top:0;left:0}.ct-chart.ct-major-twelfth{display:block;position:relative;width:100%}.ct-chart.ct-major-twelfth:before{display:block;float:left;content:"";width:0;height:0;padding-bottom:33.3333333333%}.ct-chart.ct-major-twelfth:after{content:"";display:table;clear:both}.ct-chart.ct-major-twelfth>svg{display:block;position:absolute;top:0;left:0}.ct-chart.ct-double-octave{display:block;position:relative;width:100%}.ct-chart.ct-double-octave:before{display:block;float:left;content:"";width:0;height:0;padding-bottom:25%}.ct-chart.ct-double-octave:after{content:"";display:table;clear:both}.ct-chart.ct-double-octave>svg{display:block;position:absolute;top:0;left:0}
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chartist/0.2.4/chartist.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="chart-container">
                <div class="ct-chart"></div>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

if you give height in the options like

```
var options = {
                    seriesBarDistance: 10,
                    fullWidth: true,
                    showArea:true,
                    height:'500px'

            };
new Chartist.Bar('.ct-chart', dataArray, options, responsiveOptions );
```

It will increase the overall height and spacing too.
Thanks
Kiran.

Comment: code formatting here is a bit ... tricky (was for me, as a beginner :) - code lines need an indentation of 4 spaces each, to properly indent, you can select the lines and press ctrl-k

Comment: I don't see these properties in the [API](https://gionkunz.github.io/chartist-js/api-documentation.html#chartistcore-method-times)

Comment: Please check this link https://gionkunz.github.io/chartist-js/examples.html all properties are available in the API.